# If once value assigned to a variable in objective c while application install then how to access that value at every time of opening an application?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am new to objective C.

If once value assigned to a variable in objective c while application install then how to access that value at every time of opening an application? And i tried with extern, static. Each will assign and sets the value at first time. If i rerun the application in emulator, it is not taking that last assigned value.

If anything is possible other than File system storage ? Is it possible with static or extern variables.

Scenario:

While install "extern int test" is assigned to 10 then it changed to 20. While accessing from another class, test reflects 20. If i rerun the app, "test" is showing "10"

But i want to access the last assigned the value (like static in java)

Thanks for any help !

Comment: After closing the app the data stored in variables will be lost, so you need to use NSUserDefaults

Comment: You may try with NSUserDefault.

Comment: "Variables" do not persist from one invocation of the app to the next (not even in a singleton).  If you want to store a value from one execution of your app to the next, use NSUserDefaults.  If you want some action to occur at startup, you should generally do it in your AppDelegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because all variables of Objective C program are stored in memory, none of them survives application termination. If you need the value to be available after your app restarts, you have several options:

- **Use the file system** - this one is the most straightforward thing to do. Cocoa provides APIs for writing strings to files in a single go, so your code would be short and simple.
- **Use user defaults** - This API helps you persist values for reuse in an organized way.
- **Use keychain APIs** - This API lets you save small amounts of data that must be encrypted. This is probably an overkill in your scenario.

Answer (score 3):

After closing the app the data stored in variables do not persist (of all classes), so you need to use NSUserDefaults (in your case)

The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs.
At runtime, you use an NSUserDefaults object to read the defaults that your application uses from a user’s defaults database.
user's defaults database persists when app is killed.

Use NSUSerDefaults value will remain saved until application is deleted

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:obj1 forKey:key1];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and access value like

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

id obj = [defaults objectForKey:key1];
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP what he's doing wrong and how your answer solves his issue (which it **does** solve, IMHO).

Answer (score 3):

Use NSUserDefaults to set the value in AppDelegate :

```
NSUserDefaults defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:20  forKey:@"abc"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

TO get the value again, Use this method :

```
NSUserDefaults defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
var = [defaults integerForKey:@"abc"];
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP what he's doing wrong and how your answer solves his issue (which it does solve, IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

All the variables are store in Memory once will restart your application the memory is released by ARC and allocated by new one memory address

Can user FileSystem or NSUserDefaults in objective c